# Django, Sqlalchemy: Cannot drop table ganalytics_article because other objects depend on it

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy

I have this models in my Django `ganalytics` app:

```
class Article(models.Model):
        id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
        article_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        article_url = models.URLField(max_length=250)
        article_pub_date = models.DateField()
    

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Author(models.Model):
    author_sf_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

  
class AuthorArticleCompany(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author,
                               to_field="id",
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='authorarticle_author_id')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,
                                to_field="id",
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='authorarticle_company_id')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article,
                                to_field="id",
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='authorarticle_article_id')

   


class Ganalytics(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='ganalytics_author_id')
    totalview = models.IntegerField()
    totalinteractions = models.IntegerField()

   


class Unsubscribers(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    reasonwhy = models.CharField(max_length=90)
```

I am running pandas to_sql to upload the database:

```
authorarticlecompanydf.to_sql("ganalytics_authorarticlecompany", con=engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
articledf.to_sql("ganalytics_article",con=engine,if_exists="replace",index=False)
company_name.to_sql("ganalytics_company",con=engine,if_exists="replace",index=False)
authordf.to_sql("ganalytics_author", con=engine,if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

I am getting this error message:

```
DETAIL:  constraint ganalytics_ganalytic_article_id_d37f2464_fk_ganalytic on table ganalytics_ganalytics depends on table ganalytics_article
constraint ganalytics_authorart_article_id_7f4ff374_fk_ganalytic on table ganalytics_authorarticlecompany depends on table ganalytics_article
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.

[SQL: 
DROP TABLE ganalytics_article]
```

I have tried to change the `on_delete` field to different values but it wont help.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

What is the command you are running to get the error?  The bottom line is `Ganalytics` depends on `Article` via the FK between them. By dropping `Article` first you are breaking that dependency. You either need to `DROP` `Ganalytics` first and then `Article` or follow the hint `DROP ... CASCADE`. Though be aware that will `DROP` `Ganalytics` also.

**UPDATE**

Another option would be to drop the FK between the two tables. Then you would not have the dependency issue.

Comment: Sorry for the update @Adrian, I am using Pandas for the upload. I just update the question

Comment: Well according to your code it should just be appending records. The error says it is trying to `DROP ganalytics_article` so something is up. I would tail the Postgres log to see what is actually happening.

Comment: my bad. I is `if_exists="replace"`

Comment: That would be the problem. You are dropping `ganalytics_article` while `ganalytics_ganaltics` still exists and depends on it. I don't see anything in `to_sql` that will allow you to override that. You are going to have to do this manually. Either drop `ganalytics_ganaltics`  and repopulate it later or manually `TRUNCATE`  ganalytics_article`  and use `if_exists='replace'`.

Comment: A stupid on my part, that should have been `if_exists='append'`